# query in oracle(sql)10g

Tags: sql

i have a table like this

```
Name         Skills
mahesh       c,c++,java
santosh      Java
srikanth     c
```

in this i need people who know c. i am not getting the query can u help me out. or i should break the skills colums... if yes then how should i break and achive my query... please can you anser me.....

Comment: Out of curiosity why is this tagged with `user32`? Other than that could you show what you have tried so far that didn't work? Some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

it is a bad idea to store multiple values in a single column, instead either have multiple rows or a link table.

Multiple rows would appear as:

```
mahesh    c
mahesh    c++
mahesh    java
santosh   java
srikanth  c
```

For a link table approach you might have three tables: Person, Skill and PersonSkill. Something like like this:

```
Person
ID  Name
1   mahesh
2   santosh
3   scrikanth

Skill
ID  Description
1   C
2   C++
3   Java

PersonSkill
PersonID    SkillID
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           3
3           1
```

you would then query for people who have the C skill as follows:

```
select Name 
from Person, Skill, PersonSkill
where Person.ID = PersonID and Skill.ID = SkillID and Skill.Description = 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case that mahesh didn't design the database but just has to query it:

```
select Name 
from yourTable
where ',' || SKills || ',' like '%,c,%';
```